# Counting the elements in a list of lists using a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, typeerror

How do I convert this list of lists

`[['shall', 'prove'], ['shall', 'not'], ['shall', 'go'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'defend'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'fight'], ['shall', 'never']]`

into a dictionary which counts how many times each element appears in the list?

i.e. `['shall', 'fight']` appears 7 times

I've tried things like this

```
def word_counter(input_str):
    counts = {}
    for w in input_str:
        counts[w] = counts.get(w, 0) + 1
    items = counts.items()
word_counter([['of', 'god'], ['of', 'his'], ['of', 'her'], ['of', 'god']])
```

where I'd like the output to be something like

```
{['of', 'god']: 2, ['of', 'his']: 2, ['of', 'her']: 1}
```

but I get

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Ideally I'd like to do this in basic Python without the need for any extra libraries etc.
Thank you

Comment: Lists can not be used as dict keys.

Comment: What if I first converted it to a list of tuples so I had something like [('of', 'god'), ('of', 'his'), ('of', 'her'), ('of', 'god')]?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list elements into `str` so you can use them as keys in the dictionary:

```py
def word_counter(input_lst: list[list[str]]) -> dict[str, int]:
    counts: dict[str, int] = {}
    for pair in input_lst:
        pair = str(pair)
        if pair in counts:
            counts[pair] += 1
        else:
            counts[pair] = 1

    return counts


# Output: {"['of', 'god']": 2, "['of', 'his']": 1, "['of', 'her']": 1}
print(word_counter([['of', 'god'], ['of', 'his'], ['of', 'her'], ['of', 'god']]))
```

And just convert them back to list if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are mutable objects, they cannot be hashed and thus cannot be used as keys in a dictionary. You can use tuples which are immutable sequences similar to lists. Also, counting is already implemented in python in the `collections` module in the standard library (you don’t have to install any additional libraries). Here is an example:

```py
import collections

original = [('shall', 'prove'), ('shall', 'not'), ('shall', 'go'), ('shall', 'fight'),
            ('shall', 'fight'), ('shall', 'fight'), ('shall', 'defend'), ('shall', 'fight'),
            ('shall', 'fight'), ('shall', 'fight'), ('shall', 'fight'), ('shall', 'never')]

counts = collections.Counter(original)
# counts is a Counter object which is a subclass of dict, but
# if you want a normal dict add the line below
counts_as_dict = dict(counts)
```